# Chrome re-downloading same images each time in same session

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, http, caching

I'm new to React and I'm trying to serve some files from either my `public` folder or any remote URL. No matter where I request the images from, my browser always re-downloads same images over and over again. For example (though this applies to *all* images in my React app), I change something in my state that creates an image object with some `src` (just a regular `<img src...>`, nothing special). Then I do something that causes another image to load the same resource. Browser should normally serve the image immediately from cache, but it instead downloads the same image again. Here are the request/response headers for one of the images (but as I said it happens with *all* images regardless of them being served from `localhost` or a remote host):

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/images/content-icons/small/button-question@2x.png
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000

Response Headers: 

Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 479
Content-Type: image/png
Date: Sun, 01 Mar 2020 10:03:41 GMT
ETag: W/"1df-1707cbf1a8e"
Last-Modified: Tue, 25 Feb 2020 14:27:43 GMT
X-Powered-By: Express

Request Headers:

Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36
```

This problem is occuring on Chrome (v80) and I've triple-checked that `Disable cache` checkbox is *not checked*. Apparently, there's no problem with Safari; it caches and serves from memory correctly.

What is going on with Chrome and caching?

Comment: `Cache-Control: no-cache` and `Pragma: no-cache` in request headers. `max-age=0` in response header. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: Also read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#Cache_validation

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli weird, it's an app created with `create-react-app` and I haven't done anything regarding cache. I have no idea how caching is even configured in React anyway.

Comment: I just double checked the app I'm currently working on, also bootstrapped with Create React App (`"react-scripts": "^3.3.0"`) and Chrome 80 is properly fetching cached versions of images after they're loaded.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 this is weird. I haven't changed anything either. something is probably intercepting the requests at some point.

Comment: If you haven't yet, you could try running `localhost:3000` in a new Incognito window to ensure that none of your Chrome extensions are causing the issue (assuming that your extensions are not active in Incognito mode).  Further, I'd try running your code on a different machine or separate user to see if you can produce the same bug.  Finally, you could try reinstalling Chrome.